# Specification of a mixed model using glmmLasso package

Tags: r, regression, mixed-models, lasso-regression, random-effects

I have a dataset containing repeated measures and quite a lot of variables per observation. Therefore, I need to find a way to select explanatory variables in a smart way. Regularized Regression methods sound good to me to address this problem.

Upon looking for a solution, I found out about the **glmmLasso** package quite recently. However, I have difficulties defining a model. I found a demo file online, but since I'm a beginner with R, I had a hard time understanding it.

(demo: https://rdrr.io/cran/glmmLasso/src/demo/glmmLasso-soccer.r)

Since I cannot share the original data, I would suggest you use the soccer dataset (the same dataset used in glmmLasso demo file). The variable **team** is repeated in observations and should be taken as a random effect.

```
# sample data

library(glmmLasso)
data("soccer")
```

I would appreciate if you can explain the parameters *lambda* and *family*, and how to tune them.

Comment: Hi! Take a look to this explanation which includes an example with `soccer` dataset. https://rdrr.io/cran/glmmLasso/man/glmmLasso.html

Comment: @R18 Thank you, but I'm more interested in learning how to tune lambda and give the model the starting values for the very first fit.

Comment: I assume you've seen these two posts? https://davidabugaber.com/blog/f/find-the-optimal-mixed-model-for-your-data-with-glmmlasso and https://www.aggieerin.com/post/lasso-myself-numbers/